# Laravel (API) Passport Token Security

Tags: security, token, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel (7x) web app, and an API for front-end. I use Laravel Passport for this communication.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

There is a basic question: After my login request Laravel returns a token, and I can connect to API, its okay. **BUT, how can I protect the token?**

I mean that someone can steal the token on user side; when front-end send any requests to server with token, right? At this point how should we protect the token? For example; for each request we should not send request for a new token?

Thanx!

Comment: You can shorten the token lifetime, ask a new authentification if IP address changed and add mobile authentification to improve security of user authentification, but you can't protect the token from being stolen on the user side.

Comment: Actually, I use the API for front-end web side, not for a mobile app. I just want to answer request, if the request comes from my front-end. _"but you can't protect the token from being stolen on the user side."_ if like this, how possible making a "secure" back-end API?

Comment: The token is in the applicative layer. If you are using https, every request is ciphered, including headers. 
The token can be stolen on an infected computer, but can't be stolen on an infected network, since many browser are preventing the connection if the certificate is wrong or self-signed (protecting from MITM or else).